# Exception for UAC

Tags: windows-7, boot, uac

I use a application called Everything (just google it) which automatically starts after I login. After I loged in, the UAC dialog appears which I must confirm with yes. This is a bit annoying each time I start my computer to confirm this dialog. Is there a way in Windows 7 to give this application an exception, so that the UAC dialog wont't appear each time I log in?

Answer (score 1):

See this WinTuts' article: [Disable User Account Control (UAC) for certain Windows Vista applications](http://www.wintuts.com/Disable-UAC-for-certain-applications).  That page is written for Vista, but it probably works on Windows 7 too.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't test [Fran's way](https://superuser.com/a/436334/373304). Anyway, I've found a manual on a different workaround [using shortcuts](http://www.techsupportalert.com/content/how-create-program-shortcut-run-without-uac-prompt-windows-7.htm), designed especially for Windows 7. I have just tested it and it works.

The algorithm (images in the [linked page](http://www.techsupportalert.com/content/how-create-program-shortcut-run-without-uac-prompt-windows-7.htm)):

> The trick makes use of Windows Task Scheduler to create a task with
>   highest privileges. The task is then used in a shortcut. First, create
>   the task:
>
> 1. Open Task Scheduler by entering “sched” (without quotes) in the
>      Start search box. Another way is  Control Panel-System and
>      Security-Administrative Tools-Schedule tasks.
> 2. In the right pane of the Task Scheduler interface (shown in a
>      previous tip), click “Create Task”.
> 3. The dialog shown below will open.
> 4. Give the task a name. You will need to use this later.
> 5. Be sure to check the box by “Run with highest privileges”. This is
>      what keeps the UAC prompt from popping up.
> 6. Click the tab “Actions”
> 7. Click the button "New..."
> 8. The dialog window shown below will open.
> 9. Enter or browse to the full path and name of the program you want to
>      run. If it has spaces,  enclose the entire path and name in
>      quotation marks.
> 10. Click "OK"
> 11. If you are using a laptop or other battery-powered device, click
>        the "Conditions" tab and remove any power settings that might
>        interfere with running on a battery.
> 12. Click “OK”
>
> Next, you create a shortcut to run the task:
>
> 1. Right-click on an empty spot on the desktop.
> 2. In the context menu that opens, choose New—Shortcut.
> 3. In the box under “Type the location of the item”, enter `schtasks /run /tn "your_taskname"` where `your_taskname` is what was used in
>      step 4 above. Be sure to keep quotes around the task name.
> 4. Click “Next”
> 5. Enter a name for the shortcut.
> 6. Click “Finish”
> 7. Place the shortcut anywhere convenient.

[Another version](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/11949-elevated-program-shortcut-without-uac-prompt-create.html?filter[2]=Shortcuts) of the same workaround adds one more step, adding appropriate icon (again, I didn't copy images from the linked page):

> 1. Click/tap on the Shortcut tab, and on the Change Icon button.
> 2. Click/tap on OK.
> 3. Click/tap on the Browse button.
> 4. Navigate to the .exe file of the program that you have created this
>      shortcut with, select it, and click/tap on Open.
> 5. Select the icon you want for the shortcut, then click/tap on OK.
> 6. Click/tap on OK.

Place the shortcut to your startup folder instead of your desktop to start the program at the start of the OS (and remove the original shortcut from there, you don't need the program being run twice).